# Auto login doesn't seem to work for me all the time, when is it suppose to work?

Tags: support

If I login to 1 stachexchange website, sometimes when I go to another one it automatically logs me in.  Sometimes this happens on the main page, and other times it happens when I try and post.

On the other hand, sometimes it just doesn't autologin at all and I have to go to myopenid.

Comment: Which browser are you using on which OS.